# Не найден конвертер для списка сущностей jaxb?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

В рест-апи использую для обмена с внешним миром xml.
Для xml пользуюсь библиотекой jaxb и конвертормми:

```
converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
converters.add(new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter());
converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
```

Но один из рестов должен возвращать не просто сущность, а список созданных мною сущностей, например `List<User>`, но получаю ошибку:

> No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

При попытке добавить конвертеры:

```
converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
```

Требуется зависимость на faster.xml, который конфликтует с jaxb и приложение перестает стартовать. Что делать?

Comment: а какой ответ в формате xml вы ожидаете от рест эндпоинта возвращающего список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил класс

@XmlRootElement("root")
Users{

@XmlElementWrapper("users)
   List user;
}

и с бэкенда передаю на фронт не User, a Users.